# behaviour of implicit function declaration

Tags: c, function-declaration, implicits, function-definition

I know it is wrong to use a function without  prototype.
But when  I was fiddling around, I came across this *strange* and *conflicting*  behavior.

**test1**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <limits.h>
    void main(){
        char c='\0';
        float f=0.0;
           xof(c,f);/* at this point implicit function declaration is 
generated as int xof(int ,double ); */ 
    }
    int xof(char c,float f)
    {
        printf("%d %f\n", c,f);
    }
```

*Implicit function declaration would be  int xof(int ,double );*

error is

> variablename.c:8:5: error: conflicting types for 'xof'  int xof(char
>   c,float f)

I understand this because **implicitly generated function declaration** (which defaults integer values to INT and decimals to DOUBLE) doesn't match the following function definition

**test2**

```
#include <stdio.h>


 #include <limits.h>
    void main(){
        unsigned int a =UINT_MAX;
        int b=0;
        xof(a); /* implicit function declaration should be int xof(int); */
    }

    int xof(unsigned a,int b)
    {
        printf("%d %d\n", a,b);
    }
```

*implicit function declaration would be int xof(int);* which should conflict with function definition

But this runs fine **( no error)** and output is 
with **'a'** behaving as 'int' value and **'b'** has 'undefined Garbage'

> -1 12260176

Could someone explain this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: C requires a correct declaration preceeding usage. Anything else is not valid C! Hence it is pointless to ask "why this C code does something - it is not C code and you don't use a standard compliant compiler or ignore warnings. And according to your intro you are well aware.

Comment: Older versions of the C standard allowed function argument inference. The 2nd example can "sneak" though these loose rules.  This is one of the reasons C has moved to always requiring a forward declaration.

Comment: Just update to a compiler that isn't older than 18 years. Then you don't have to ponder these things.

Comment: Vote to reopen.  The linked dup asks if function prototypes are necessary.  This question asks in what cases an implicit declaration can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a function call is encountered without a definition, the implicit definition generated will always be `int (*)()`, i.e. a function accepting an unspecified number of arguments and returning `int`.  The actual arguments in the function call are **not** taken into account.  That is where your misconception comes from.

In the case of the first program, the generated error message is:

> /tmp/x1.c:10: error: conflicting types for ‘xof’
>  /tmp/x1.c:10:
>   note: an argument type that has a default promotion can’t match an
>   empty parameter name list declaration
>  /tmp/x1.c:6: error: previous
>   implicit declaration of ‘xof’ was here

The error appears because the actual function definition contains one or more parameters whose types are subject to default promotion rules.  Specifically, any integer type with a rank lower than `int` (a `char` in this case) is promoted to `int` in an expression.  The same goes for the `float` argument which gets promoted to a `double` in expressions.  In other words, it's impossible to pass parameters of the correct type to this function with an implicit declaration.

The second program doesn't generate an error because neither of the arguments (`int` and `unsigned int`) are subject to default promotion rules.  In this case, you invoke undefined behavior because you aren't passing the proper number of arguments of the correct types.  If you did pass in 2 parameters of the correct types, the behavior would be well defined.

Note that implicit function declarations are a C89 feature and are not supported in C99 and later, although some compilers may still accept them in C99 or C11 mode as an extension.